# Grouping Results from database

Tags: php

I am trying to display results in category's based on id I get the information from the data base but it creates a category header all over again.

For example:

> title category demo cat 1
> topic 1 cat 1
>
> title category demo cat 1
> topic 2 cat 1
>
> title category demo cat 2
> topic 3 cat 2

When it should display:

> title category demo cat 1
> topic 1 cat 1
>
> topic 2 cat 1
>
> title category demo cat 2
> topic 3 cat 2

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM forums, forum_categories WHERE forum_categories.cat_id = forums.cat_id ORDER BY forum_categories.cat_id";
$result = query($sql);

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {
         
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];    
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
    
    echo "<thead>";
             echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<th colspan='4'>$cat_title</th>";
            "</tr>";
         echo "</thead>";
         echo "<tbody>";
                      
  
    $forums_cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
    $forum_name = $row['forum_name']; 
    $forum_desc = $row['forum_desc'];
    $forum_last_post_id = $row['forum_last_post_id'];
    
    echo "<tr>";
    
    echo "<td>$forums_cat_id</td>";
    echo "<td>$forum_name<br>$forum_desc<br>Admin</td>";
    echo "<td>0</td>";
    echo "<td>0</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: then keep track of what header you've already output, and only output a new header when things change. e.g. `$prev = null; while(...) { if ($prev != $cur) { output $cur; $prev = $cur; } }`

Comment: Marc B thank you for your help I am fairly new to php can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the header for each result MySQL returns, for each row. So you're not distinguishing whenever a "new" category is found. This can be done fairly simple by creating a temporary variable like an array. For example:

```
$displayedCategories = array();

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {
    if (!in_array($row['cat_id'], $displayedCategories)) {
        // This is a new category, display it and save it in $displayedCategories
        $displayedCategories[] = $row['cat_id'];
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th colspan='4'>$cat_title</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
    }

    // Do the other stuff here...
}
```

This way, any "new" category that's not encountered, the header is printed once and the category id is saved to the `$displayedCategories` array. If the same category is encountered again, the header will not be output again.

Comment: Oldskool I appreciate the fact that you explain it to me instead of just posting code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover"><tbody>
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM forums, forum_categories WHERE forum_categories.cat_id = forums.cat_id ORDER BY forum_categories.cat_id";
    $result = query($sql);
    $cur_cat = '';
    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

        $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];    
        $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];

        if($cat_title != $cur_cat) {
            echo "<thead>";
                 echo "<tr>";
                     echo "<th colspan='4'>$cat_title</th>";
                "</tr>";
            echo "</thead>";
            $cur_cat = $cat_title;
         }


        $forums_cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
        $forum_name = $row['forum_name']; 
        $forum_desc = $row['forum_desc'];
        $forum_last_post_id = $row['forum_last_post_id'];

        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>$forums_cat_id</td>";
        echo "<td>$forum_name<br>$forum_desc<br>Admin</td>";
        echo "<td>0</td>";
        echo "<td>0</td>";  
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    ?>
</tbody></table>
```